# User roles array vs string

Tags: frameworks, user-interface, authorization

I'm working on a meanjs project.  The user roles are set as an array:

`roles = ['admin', 'user', 'manager'];`

why not just set it like this?

`role = 'admin'`

Why is the convention of an array used rather than just setting a role value as a string?

Comment: If a user can ever have more than one role, the roles would naturally be stored in a collection, no?

Comment: Right but I'm saying why would they ever need to have more than 1 role?  Unless you're storing certain resources paths along with those roles, why have more than 1 role?

Comment: Ok, that's a different question. I would say it's quite common to have systems where users can have more than one role. In those situations, storing the roles in an array is appropriate. If the system you are modeling has a 'one role per user' rule, then you wouldn't need the array.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole idea of role based access control is that any user can fulfil multiple roles. In simple system, each role may be a superset of another role, e.g. `admin > manager > user`. But this doesn't have to be the case.

The most obvious example is when we have multiple instances of a resource, and a role only applies to a single instance. E.g. one user could be admin on server-5 and server-3, but not on any other server where they only are a user. This would necessitate a setup like

```
roles = ['admin-5', 'admin-3', 'user']
```

It is also possible that a system has multiple roles that are separate rather than subsets of permissions. E.g. an FTP server can be configured so that anyone may upload data but not download it, but also in a way that everyone can download data but not upload any. So different users would have different role sets:

```
user1 = ['uploader']
user2 = ['downloader']
user3 = ['uploader', 'downloader']
```

So why don't we create a super-role that has both permissions? Why not `user3 = ['fullaccess']`? When permissions are connected to a single role rather than a group of roles, this makes permissions easier to manage (issue, view, revoke) and to implement. To check whether a user may upload:

```
if UPLOADER in roles:
  ok
```

With roles that inherit from another, this would either become

```
if role == UPLOADER or role == FULLACCESS:
  ok
```

which is difficult to extends when creating a new super-role that includes the uploader permission.

Or if we introduce an inheritance system where each permission may involve a complicated check:

```
if role.permits(UPLOAD):
  ok
```

Clearly, these are more complicated. When implementing security, complexity is *dangerous*. Too easy to introduce a hard-to-see bug that grants anyone permission.

Considering that RBAC is simple for both users and developers, it's not surprising it is common in state-of-the-art systems.

(This answer does not discuss the difference between roles and permissions, which introduces an additional layer of mappings.)